# 404 page rendering on every url [using React-router]

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm following the basic example on reacttraining.com

So far everything is working excepto for the No Match page.

If I use the exact same code they show:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
    <Redirect from="/old-match" to="/will-match"/>
    <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch}/>
    <Route component={NoMatch}/>
 </Switch
```

the NoMatch component should render only when the url doesn't match any other component.

instead, it's rendering on every url, including the ones with components.

they say that

> A  with no path always matches

but shouldn't that rule apply only for componentless urls?

What Am I doing wrong?

Also, on the same topic: How can I Render an entire page for a route, and not only render the component on the same page?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Gonzalo. There's definitely something weird going on. Are you sure you have the right version of the router installed? I say this because the examples on the website are literally using the example code under the hood. So if it works on the website, it should 100% work irl (because it really is using that code under the hood).

Comment: For the last question, you can put an array of components in a route with `components` prop like this `<Route path="groups" components={{main: Groups, sidebar: GroupsSidebar}} />`

Comment: I have this same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your code, you have 3 route:

1) `\` as your root of your project

2) `old-match` that you want to redirect to will-match

3) `will-match` that want to show `WillMatch` component

and unknown route must be render `NoMatch` component.
for this purpose its better to implement this approach that you said above for your routes to handle redirect and 404 component:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route exact={true} path='/old-match' render={() => { return <Redirect to="/will-match" />; }} />
    <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```